Is looking up the lyrics for a song illegal?
I was dumbstruck when I found out today that apparently posting the lyrics to a song is copyright infringement. I literally asked ChatGPT for the lyrics to "Around the World" by Daft Punk, and it said that would be copyright infringement. The lyrics are literally just "Around the World" repeated over and over again (hopefully I'm not breaking the law by saying so <.<).

Firstly, how can this be the law? Bob heard a song that said "haters gonna hate hate hate", and he's not allowed to state those words he heard? What's stopping Taylor Swift from suing every person who's said "haters gonna hate hate hate"?
But anyways, my actual question is: when I look up the lyrics for a song, am I breaking the law, just as surely as if I tried to steal a car or pirate a movie?
Or is this just technically a "law", but it's never actually enforced to any significant degree?

@Jen "when I look up the lyrics of the song, am I breaking the law". I'm asking whether looking up the lyrics is illegal (similar to how pirating a movie is illegal).

It is not illegal to look up the lyrics to a song.
At this Q&A (Why Genius doesn't have problems with lyrics copyright?), it's explained that Genius has a licence to share lyrics. So does Spotify. Artists or labels themselves might share their lyrics. Correspondingly, it is not illegal for you to try to find those.

So to be clear: it's legal if you find the lyrics on a website that has a legal contract that allows them to tell you the lyrics. But what about if you happen upon a website that doesn't have an explicit legal contract to tell you those lyrics? There's a lot of slightly obscure japanese songs whose lyrics I look up, and none of them are on "Genius" or Spotify. Am I supposed to make sure that the website I read the lyrics from has an explicit legal contract with the rights-holder of the song?

Just as a simple example, when I look up "I'll Remember You Falcom lyrics" on Google, I don't get any website that has a legal contract with those who made the song. I get 2 fan websites that just post the lyrics. Am I essentially pirating when I view these lyrics from websites that clearly don't have legal contracts? Just as surely as if I watched some movie on an illegal streaming website?

I think this answer could be considerably improved by clearing up the OPs misconception that they infringe copyright by looking at something, compared to the publishing party.

ChatGPT did not claim your acts of searching for the lyrics or attempted reading of the lyrics are copyright infringement.
ChatGPT claimed it would commit copyright infringement if it were to provide the lyrics to you, therefore it would not provide the lyrics to you.
Your act of searching for lyrics does not amount to copyright infringement.
Your act of reading lyrics on a website does not amount to copyright infringement, whether or not the website itself infringed copyright.
If you were to make a permanent copy of the lyrics or publish the lyrics on your own website, etc, those might be copyright infringing acts.
This is about what some jurisdictions call 'the exclusive right of reproduction'. Who has the right to reproduce, copy, distribute, share, the copyrighted work.
Evidently, ChatGPT does not have such a right, e.g. a licence, to reproduce the lyrics.

You can also sing the lyrics (provided you are not giving a public performance), you just can’t write them down.
